# Blackberry Browser - error encountered during xml parse

Tags: xml, blackberry, xml-parsing

I am trying to test a web page using jQuery mobile on a blackberry 9650 5.0 device with the native browser. I got XML Parser error - Matching End tag not found for Start Tag < head >. I resolved the head element by including end tags for all the sub tags - ex: instead of using "< link ... / >", I changed to "< link > < / link >". Now the header shows up but I still see the following error:

Error encountered during xml parse. Expecting a name.

How do I resolve this? The problem seems to exist on native blackberry browser. Opera Mini displayed it fine. But I need it working on the native browser. Please help.